# How can I set a variable in Oracle and then reuse it in a query?

Tags: mysql, database, oracle

Basically I am doing this in MySQL but I want to do this in Oracle want to do this:

```
SET @max_number_value := (SELECT MAX(random_column_with_number_as_values) from some_table)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
declare
max_number_value some_table.random_column_with_number_as_values%TYPE;
begin
   SELECT MAX(random_column_with_number_as_values) 
   INTO max_number_value
   FROM some_table;
END;
```